# How to select only date portion of a bigint?

Tags: mysql

Assuming in mysql I have a table with column "thedate" of BIGINT with the value:

```
1342962983638
```

which translates to 2012-07-22 _*some time here*
How can I perform a select statement that selects only the date portion from this bigint?

i.e. the resulting bigint would show up as "2012-07-22"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to truncate the `epochtime` to just 10 integer values. So, the select would look like:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME( SUBSTRING('1342962983638',1,10), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4c9f/3).

Comment: +1 Yes this is better than my implementation. I'll delete mine.